# Google Geocoder componentrestrictions not filtering

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

Here is my string I'm passing to the geocoder service.

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=Lindon&region=GB&componentRestrictions=locality

where region=GB is country code for United Kingdom and instead of London I'm passing in Lindon. Componentrestrictions=locality should be for cities only!

But my results are coming back with some location in the USA!!

Is this not how you use component restrictions for google geocoder?

I don't want to see any results here if 'Lindon' is passed in, especially not for the USA.

Answer (score 1):

1. there is no parameter `componentRestrictions`(this parameter belongs to the Javascript-API), the parameter for the Webservice is called `components`
2. a component must have a name(e.g. `locality`) **and** a value. In your case, when you want to search for a city called **Lindon** it should be `locality:Lindon`
3. the `region`-parameter doesn't restrict the results, it will only prefer results from the given region.
   Use the component `country:gb` when you want to restrict the results to GB.

Sample-request for a city **Washington** (as it seems there is no city [**Lindon** in the UK](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?components=locality:Lindon%7Ccountry:gb))

[`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?components=locality:Washington|country:gb`](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?components=locality:Washington|country:gb)

Comment: what is %7 in your Lindon query? or why did you use a | in one query and a %7 in the other?

Comment: can you provide a link to where it says 'components' and not 'componentrestrictions' I'm using this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ComponentFiltering

Comment: the %7 is the encoded Pipe(the separator when you use multiple components). I did use the Pipe in my answer(the Lindon-Link has been modified by SO). When you request the service you should always encode the parameters.

Comment: Geocoding-API(the Webservice): https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ComponentFiltering

Answer (score 0):

Add ",GB" for address parameter.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=Lindon,UK&region=GB&componentRestrictions=locality&language=en
[image]

The region parameter is just "biasing", not restricted the area.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRegionCodes

In my experience, adding country code, zip code, works for all most cases.